# phpexcel in zend framework 2 Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpexcel

I need to import data from an excel sheet and integrate PHPExcel in Zend framework 2.

I place the PHPExcel in vendor. Also I came to know after google that PHPExcel has no namespace so we can use the class as root class like `\PHPExcel_IOFactory`

But I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found
```

Please help!

Comment: no composer used for PHPExcel

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Manually placing a 3rd party library directory into the vendor without telling to your autoloader about the new namespace of the library and it's path is not enough.

Try to use composer. Open the command line and simply type:

```
$ cd /your/zf2/project/root
$ rm -rf vendor/PHPExcel*
$ php composer.phar selfupdate
$ php composer.phar require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

If you already have a system-wide composer installation:

```
$ composer selfupdate
$ composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Comment: FYI It looks like they moved their repo to phpoffice/phpexcel: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I found a another simple solution for this problem by including the PHPExcel_IOFactory class file in vendor/autoload.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel/PHPExcel' . '/IOFactory.php';
```

and this is also working for me.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that adding manually the PHPExcel, will not be updated the  autoload classes configuration.
I suggest, for an easy integration of [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library into zend framework 2, to use the zf2 module [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel). 
Using this module you'll avoid to have problems with PHPExcel autoloading classes.
Once installed in your application, you'll be able to use as a Service and create, modify and read excel files (including pdf, xlsx, odt)